# Animated change of opacity on hover is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-animate, opacity

I want to simply change the opacity of every item slowly inside the slider, except the one i'm hovering. It works perfect in chrome but not working a bit in Internet Explorer both 8 and 7.

Here is the html code:

```
        <div id="carousel-image-and-text" class="touchcarousel carousel-image-and-text clearfix" style="overflow: visible; ">
            <div class="touchcarousel-wrapper grab-cursor">
                <ul id="weekly-promos" class="touchcarousel-container" style="width: 1420px; left: 0px; ">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="RList" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li class="touchcarousel-item">
                                <a class="item-block" href="Article.aspx?PageID=<%# Eval("PageID") %>" rel="tooltip-<%# Eval("PageID") %>">
                                <figure><img src="<%# SetConf(Eval("PageID").ToString(),false) %><%# Eval("VisualSource") %>"></figure>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and here is the javascript part:

```
 $(".carousel-slider a img").hover(function () {
            $(".carousel-slider img").not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: '0.4', filter: 'alpha(opacity=40)' }, 1000);

        }, function () {
            $(".carousel-slider img").not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: '1.0', filter: 'alpha(opacity=100)' }, 1000);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

do not use filter, just opacity:

```
$(".carousel-slider a img").hover(function () {
  $(".carousel-slider img").not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.4 }, 500);
}, function () {
  $(".carousel-slider img").not(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
});
```